# Order values in specific way based on values in group before and after

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, data-structures

I have a task where i need to read a table from a database that looks like following for example:

```
------------------------------------
|   id    |   value   |    date    |
------------------------------------
|   1     |   val1    | 23-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
|   2     |   val2    | 23-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
|   3     |   val1    | 24-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
|   4     |   val2    | 24-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
|   5     |   val3    | 24-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
|   6     |   val1    | 25-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
|   7     |   val3    | 25-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
|   8     |   val2    | 26-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
|   9     |   val3    | 26-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
```

In the table, i could do grouping by the date, which would result in 4 groups (23-12-2020, 24-12-2020, 25-12-2020, 26-12-2020). I need to determine the first and the last element of each of the groups. The last element for date 23-12-2020 directly influences the first element for the group on date 24-12-2020 in some continuous fashion. That for example could result in both:

```
------------------------------------  or  ------------------------------------ 
|   id    |   value   |    date    |      |   id    |   value   |    date    |
------------------------------------      ------------------------------------
|   1     |   val1    | 23-12-2020 |      |   2     |   val2    | 23-12-2020 |
------------------------------------      ------------------------------------
|   2     |   val2    | 23-12-2020 |      |   1     |   val1    | 23-12-2020 |
------------------------------------      ------------------------------------
|   4     |   val2    | 24-12-2020 |      |   3     |   val1    | 24-12-2020 |
------------------------------------      ------------------------------------
```

So for all elements in a group (23-12-2020), i would check if they appear in the next group (24-12-2020). If only of these elements appear there, then that element would be last in the current group (23-12-2020) and first of the next group (24-12-2020). The fact in the example is that both val1 and val2 appear in the group with the date 24-12-2020. In that case i would look at the group with the date 25-12-2020, and if both appear there, then watch next one etc. until we find the group where only one element appears which would determine the real order. If none of them appears, then the order could be any only following the constraints that the last of one group is the first of the next one.

As for the date 25-12-2020 only val1 appears, that would enforce the following order:

```
------------------------------------
|   id    |   value   |    date    |
------------------------------------
|   1     |   val1    | 23-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
|   2     |   val2    | 23-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
|   3     |   val2    | 24-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
|   4     |   val3    | 24-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
|   5     |   val1    | 24-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
|   6     |   val1    | 25-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
|   7     |   val3    | 25-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
|   8     |   val3    | 26-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
|   9     |   val2    | 26-12-2020 |
------------------------------------
```

For note, the order between the first and last element of the group which contains more than 2 elements is not important.

I'm not sure how i would do this in an efficient way, or is there really a library that would help with this, or is there a specific data structure that could solve the problem. It's relatively complex, so i did the search (maybe with not the right keywords), but could not find anything useful.

Maybe it's also solvable with a specific query.

Thanks in advance.

PS. I'm not really sure why stackoverflow bolds parts of the code

Comment: I am just lost on what you are trying to do.  Perhaps you could show the results you want and a simple explanation of the logic in those results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The input is the first table, and the output is the last table mentioned in question. So what you can see from the last table, for every date, the first value in there is the last ordered value of the date before (https://i.imgur.com/m1XY9sn.jpg). But the tricky part is that we need to somehow determine what will be the last date of some group. For group with the date 23-12-2020 we look for those values in 24-12-2020, and as they both appear there, we need to look further at 25-12-2020, looking there for val1, that would enforce the resulting output. Not sure if i helped anyhow.

Comment: . . I really don't follow.  Your data has "dates" not "groups".  I don't know what you are trying to descrdibe.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you'll want here is backtracking, starting from the end (because the order is determined backward).

In pseudocode:

```
function order(remainingGroups, previousMatch)
  if remainingGroups is empty
    return []
  group = last of remainingGroups
  if previousMatch not in group
    return false
  candidateValues = group - {previousMatch}
  if candidateValues is empty
    if order(remainingGroups - {group}, previousMatch) is a list
      list = list + {previousMatch}
      return list
  for each candidateValue
    if order(remainingGroups - {group}, candidateValue) is a list
      list = list + {candidateValue} + candidateValues + {previousMatch}
      return list
  return false

sort and group table by date
order(groups, null)
```

For your example:

```
Original table:
val1,23-12-2020
val2,23-12-2020
val2,24-12-2020
val3,24-12-2020
val1,24-12-2020
val1,25-12-2020
val3,25-12-2020
val3,26-12-2020
val2,26-12-2020

converted to groups:
23-12-2020: {val1, val2}
24-12-2020: {val1, val2, val3}
25-12-2020: {val1, val3}
26-12-2020: {val2, val3}

Starting with the last group (26-12-2020) choose a candidate, in this case val2.
  Recursively look at the next group (25-12-2020), notice that it lacks val2, return false.
Back in the first group, try another candidate (val3)
  Recursively look at the next group (25-12-2020)
  val3 exists, remove it from our list of candidates.
  Choose a candidate (val1)
    Recursively look at the next group (24-12-2020). 
    val1 exists, remove it from our list of candidates.
    Choose a candidate (val2)
      Recursively look at the next group (23-12-2020).
      val2 exists, remove it from our list of candidates.
      Choose a candidate (val1)
        Recursively look at the next group (empty)
        Return []
      Return [val1, val2]
    Return [val1, val2, val2, val3, val1]
  Return [val1, val2, val2, val3, val1, val1, val3]
Return [val1, val2, val2, val3, val1, val1, val3, val3, val2]
```

Comment: in line 5 of your code, if i start with null/None with the second argument, i need a check for it. In the 14th line i think we don't need both adding of candidate_values and {candidate} as it will make a bigger list. I added the code in Python for this and linked it here. If i start with the first value from the last group as the second argument, then i get a ok output for the first 2 tables, but the table3 always returns just False. If i start with None as the second argument, i get a wrong output for table1 and table2. https://repl.it/@stefancolic/YummySweetCoordinate